# Determine runtime complexity given a recurrence relation

Tags: recursion, runtime, computer-science, recurrence

I'm trying to understand how to determine the runtime complexity given such a recurrence relation: T(n) = 2T(n-1) - T(n-2) + 8n + 7

I'm clueless about the minuses in the T's and all I know that it has nothing to do with master's theorem. I didn't find any explanation so far so any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is *generally* aimed at specific programming questions; methodology tutorials are beyond the scope.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general methodology question.  I feel it is not specific enough for Stack Overflow.  Perhaps the Mathematics group?